# Is there a way to limit default column width?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

In *Oracle SQL Developer* selecting `VARCHAR2`, `CLOB` or `LONG` columns shows all its contents by default. Is there a way to limit this default to e.g. 20 characters, or at least not allowing columns to be bigger than the screen width?

I know I can use *Auto-fit all columns* → *on Header*, but it limits the size of columns usually too much. However, it is still easier to expand a small column, than to contract one that spans several screen widths.

Answer (score 0):

This is the default view for version 20.2 - note the CLOB doesn't display in full nor take the entire screen, it leaves room for the other columns.

You could of course always use the SUBSTR() function on your CLOBs to determine exactly how much data to show for casual browsing.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I am using version 4.1.4.21 (bundled with Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 client).

Comment: Just go to Oracle.com/sqldeveloper and download 20.2 - unzip, run the exe, say Yes to importing your 4.1 settings

Comment: Ok, now I have a newer version, and CLOBs are limited, but VARCHAR2s and LONGs still can span several screen widths.